# Vue, looking for a way to watch values/changes from a different component/js file

Tags: vue.js

So I have a plain js file which contains some stuff like functions, one of these is a function that gets a value from 1. localstorage if not present 2. vuex if not present use a default value. These values can be updated thru the whole app in several components which means that components that also are using this value neer te update this value. For now I cant seem to make this part reactive.

**helper.js**

```
export const helperFunc = () => {
    let value
    //dummy
    if(checkforlocalstorage){
       value = localstorage_value
    } else {
       value = other_value
    }

    return value       
}
```

**ComponentOne.vue**

```
<template>
   <div>{{dynamicValue}}</div>
</template>
<script>
import {helperFunc} from './plugins/helpers.js'
export default {
    data () {
        return {
        }
    },
    computed: {
        dynamicValue : function () {           
            return helperFunc()
        }
    },
}
<script>
```

**ComponentTwo.vue**
**ComponentThree.vue**

Update the values here

Comment: helper.js should be a plugin not a plain js file, then you can inject dynamicValue which is reactive with Vue.observable

Comment: okay did not know that, any examples on how to do that(still new to Vue)

Comment: you mention vuex are you using vuex? your example is not very clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

local or session storage is not a reactive data and vue can't watch them. so you better set the variable in a vuex store, this way the data is reactive and all the components can access it from everywhere in the app.

but there's a catch that you might run into and that is if you refresh the page, all the data in the store get lost and you get the initial values.

but there is one thing you can do, and that is:

1. save the variable in the `localStorage` to have it even after the page refresh
2. initialize the store state value to have the data reactive and accessible through out the app
3. update the `state` and `localStorage` every-time data changes so you can have the reactivity and also latest value in case of a page reload.

Here I show you the basic of this idea:

first you need to setup the store file with the proper `state`, `mutation` and `action`:

```
export default {
  state() {
    return {
      myVar: 'test',
    }
  },

  mutations: {
    UPDATE_MY_VAR(state, value) {
      state.myVar = value;
    }
  },

  actions: {
    updateMyVar({ commit }, value) {
      localStorage.setItem('myVar', value);
      commit('UPDATE_MY_VAR', value);
    },
    initializeMyVar({ commit }) {
      const value = localStorage.getItem('myVar');
      commit('UPDATE_MY_VAR', value);
    }
  }
}
```

then in the `beforeCreate` or `created` hook of the root component of your app you'll have:

```
created() {
  this.$store.dispatch('initializeMyVar');
}
```

this action read the data from a localStorage and initialize the `myVar` state and you can access that form everywhere like `$store.state.myVar` and this is reactive and can be watched. also if there is no localStorage and you need a fallback you can write the proper logic for this.

then whenever the data needs to be changed you can use the second action like `$store.dispatch('updateMyVar', newUpdatedValue)` which updates both the `localStorage` and the `state`.

now even with a page reload you get the latest value from the `localStorage` and the process repeats.